# Is it possible to use NPM Link for an angular library without first building the library?

Tags: angular

I have an angular library that can be built into a node module.

In order to use my local version without publishing it, and test that it is working on several apps, I am trying to use the `npm link` command.

I have done this by navigating to the dist folder of my library where package.json is found and running npm link. I then navigate to the app I want to use it and run npm link THE_LIBRARY_NAME. This works fine but if I update the library I will need to rebuild it, and when I rebuild it the link breaks so I have to repeat the steps.

If I try to link to the library itself, and not the node module it outputs, I get a 'Cant find module' error.

What am I doing wrong please?

Trying to link to the library itself does seem to actually work, I can find it in node_modules, but to clarify the import does not find that module.

Comment: Is it a separate project with the library only or combined with an application using it?

Comment: @katzz0 it is a separate project completely

Comment: If there is a possiblity to restructure your projects I recommend to use the Angular workspace project structure. This way you are able to consume the built library directly from the consumers of your project. More details and documentation: https://angular.io/guide/file-structure
I have an example for this in my repo here: https://github.com/tenkmilan/angular-workspace-example
Based on my experience it is a better approach than using `npm link`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build the library and link that, but if you build the library with watch mode, then link it, any changes after this will not require the link to be setup again. The app using the library will recompile automatically.

Comment: I am not getting this to work.  We just npm link the library dist folder (while in watch mode) then run npm link @library-name inside of the consuming app right?

Comment: Cannot make this work. Changes are not reflected in the main app.